Python discord bot ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect() not working
@bot.command(pass_context = True, help="make bot leave vc")
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send('disconnected from vc')

    else:
        await ctx.send('im not currently in a vc')


I'm trying to make a discord bot disconnect from a discord voice channel and it doesn't work. When I use the command, the bot sends "disconnected from vc" but does not actually disconnect.

Use "ctx.voice_client" directly. Should be like this:
@bot.command(pass_context = True, help = "make bot leave vc")

async def leave(ctx):
  if ctx.voice_client:
      await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
      await ctx.send('disconnected from vc')
  else:
      await ctx.send('im not currently in a vc')


I tried, but its still doesn't work.
